# Storing only task id in an array

Tags: c#, asana

I am creating a program that will automate some functions with Asana for my workplace but am a bit stuck.  I am able to submit multiple tasks to a workspace and retrieve the task ID's of each but was wondering how to take only the ID portion of the response and store it into an array or list in C#.

The response from the GET on `/tasks?workspace=<workspace-id>&assignee=me` is:

```
{"data":[{"id":2177890732156,"name":"<name of my task>"}]}
```

I want to store the id number(s) from all my tasks into an array so I can perform an addProject PUT to each of them.

I am using a serializer to put data elements into the proper dictionary for POSTing but am wondering if there is a way to reverse it and parse only the int portion of the response, store it in an array and call it back up.

The serializer code is as follows:

```
public static string GetJsonByObject(object _object)
    {
        /// Serialize to JSON
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(_object.GetType());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, _object);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

and I have been storing my requests in a byte array as follows:

```
string content;

content = GetJsonByObject(t);
bArrContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(bArrContent, 0, bArrContent.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Close();
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous.  Are you saying you already have the dictionary of (deserialized) objects, and you just want to make an array of the 'id' fields?  Or are you trying to construct that array from the serialized values, without fully deserializing the objects?

Comment: I do not have the dictionary of objects yet and am confused as to how to create it, and after how to pull the id fields only into an array.  Sorry, I'm a bit new to C# programming and am sort of "hacking" through this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to use some Regex-fu to parse out the ID fields and store them.  However, that's kindof nasty - Structured data formats like JSON and XML exist for the purpose of having someone else's parsing library do the dirty work for you.

So, suggestion 1: Use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) instead of DataContractSerializer.  It sucks less.

which leads to suggestion 2: Use a library to deserialize your data cleanly, then use Linq to grab the ID elements:

```
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(serializedData);
UInt64[] idArr = ((JArray)jobj["data"]).Select(jItem => UInt64.Parse((string)((JObject)jItem["id"]))).ToArray();
```

Now you should have the list of IDs as an array in idArr.