# How to parse simple json object without extra libraries in c#?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

This is the json object I want to parse and turn into a Dictionary:

```
[{"Id":100, "Name":"Rush", "Category":"Prog"},
 {"Id":200, "Name":"Led Zeppellin", "Category":"Rock"},
 {"Id":300, "Name":"Grumpy Lettuce", "Category":"Weird"}
]
```

I'd like to get the Id and Name from that into a `Dictionary<int, string>()`

Thanks!

Comment: use JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864.aspx

Comment: I had a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923034/storing-only-task-id-in-an-array).  But this does require the JSON.Net library.

Answer (score 1):

There is rudimentary JSON support in the .NET framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

However, I would recommend using a specialized library, JSON.NET: like http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: +1 and converting to Dictionary can be done using `ToDictionary()` extension : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  void Main()
  {
      const string thatJsonYouWrote = @"[{""Id"":100, ""Name"":""Rush"", ""Category"":""Prog""}, {""Id"":200, ""Name"":""Led Zeppellin"", ""Category"":""Rock""}, {""Id"":300, ""Name"":""Grumpy Lettuce"", ""Category"":""Weird""}]";
      IDictionary<int,string> thatThingYouWanted = ParseJsonExample(thatJsonYouWrote);
  }

  IDictionary<int,string> ParseJsonExample(string json)
  { 
      object[] items = ((object[])new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json));
      return items
         .Cast<Dictionary<string,object>>()
         .ToDictionary(_ => Convert.ToInt32(_["Id"]), _ => _["Name"].ToString());
  }
```

***Note:** you will need to reference `System.Web.Extensions.dll` and import the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace*